# How do I use the local Firebase Auth emulator and not production auth to test my users?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

My app still expects to validate users with the production firebase-auth instance, despite having initialised the auth emulator locally with:

```
firebase init emulators
```

This is the auth logic in my React app:

```
const handleLogin = () => 
  authentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword("emulator@test.com", "emulator");
```

After *handleLogin* is triggered, I get the error ***"auth/user-not-found"*** as firebase is querying the production auth instance instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call ***useEmulator*** synchronously, right after initialisation of your app’s auth instance. ***useEmulator*** takes the local emulator URL as its only argument.

You need the following wherever your firebase auth instance is initialised:

**Firebase SDK Version 9 with tree shaking**

```js
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
```

**Firebase SDK Version 8**

```js
import firebase from "./firebase-config";
import "firebase/auth";

const authentication = firebase.auth();
    
authentication.useEmulator("http://localhost:9099");
    
export default authentication;
```

Comment: Not working with the new version, btw `connectAuthEmulator` only is available, no "useEmulator".

Comment: Indeed @Mycolaos thanks for point this out, it has changed in v9, i will update the answer

Comment: I meant, that even in the new version (with `connectAuthEmulator`) this didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm using emulator in my staging environment but I can't use ssl certificate with connectAuthEmulator(), had you to deal with this?

Comment: @MarcoDiGioia I haven't no I'm afraid, not sure how that would work

Comment: for server side applications set `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST`